# How do I efficiently draw a frame in my 3D Engine?

Tags: c++, windows, 3d, gdi

I recently came up with an idea that I should make a 3d engine from scratch. I also want to involve as few libraries as possible and keep it low-level. My plan is to create a window using windows.h and then do the math and draw the frame. I tried making something similar before using GDI's functions to draw the polygons one by one but it felt inefficient. I wonder if there is a performant way of drawing a bitmap that I would beforehand fill with pixels using algorithms and such. Or is there a better way of drawing a frame?

Comment: Your question is *way* too broad, and I'm not sure you know what you're looking for either. What do you mean by "a performant way of drawing a bitmap that I would beforehand fill with pixels using algorithms and such."

Comment: I mean that I would project the 3d world into a bitmap, draw and color all of the triangles with algorithms. I believe that drawing a whole frame at a time instead of calling a drawing function for every triangle is more efficient. Is it?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [blitting function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) between your bitmap in memory and the window.

Comment: FYI: [NoGL3dDemo](https://github.com/scheff173/NoGL3dDemo) Nevertheless, rendering on GPU beats rendering on CPU by magnitudes. This isn't surprising as the CPU comes with 8 or 16 cores or so (and the rendering code has to be tailored to use them all) while the GPU may have 1000s of them (and the GPU drivers are already prepared for massive concurrency).

Comment: I guess it does the job but isn't GDI very old?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat what if I use CUDA?

Comment: to do what? implement a rasterizer? That is a bit too far-fetched for your first 3D engine, I think.

Comment: I guess I will just do it CPU accelerated for now. I will see how eager I am to make it GPU later.